# Ambiguity in the [color] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, content-level

Nine questions were tagged [color](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color).

Of these [seven related to the perceptual values of different frequencies of visible light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color), and [two related to the characteristic charge of the strong nuclear force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-charge).

For the time being I have re-tagged the latter as [color-charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-charge), but I am interested in alternate opinions on the correct tagging. Does perceptual color have a well defined place in physics, and if not should we reserve [color](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) for the quantum number of the quarks? Or is the casual usage so strongly fixed that we should keep the perceptual tag to avoid confusion for beginners?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would be in favor of keeping [color](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) to refer to the optical concept, mostly because doing otherwise is going to confuse the heck out of a lot of people who aren't familiar with QCD. Also, questions about SU(3) color charge usually can be identified well enough with [quantum-chromodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chromodynamics), although I wouldn't be opposed to keeping [color-charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-charge) around.

(I hope this is not the only answer to be posted)